# Struts Tiles taglib class not found

Tags: java

I am using `struts tiles` concept. I got an error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.UseAttributeTei
```

I have downloaded `apache.struts.1.3.8.jar` file.

Comment: You are missing struts-tiles jars, download all jars related to struts from [here](http://struts.apache.org/download.cgi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried to search `org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.UseAttributeTei` in a [JAR Search](http://www.findjar.com/index.x) and it shows that `UseAttributeTei` is only in `struts-1.2.9.jar` or lower versions.

If you want this is the link to download [struts-1.2.9](http://www.findjar.com/jar/struts/struts/1.2.9/struts-1.2.9.jar.html)